# Дано натуральное n. Определить, является ли это число палиндромом

Tags: c++

Вот мой код, но я не знаю, что делать дальше... Как мне дописать этот код, не используя массивы, указатели, строки и тому подобное... Эта задача должна решаться как-то с помощью цикла.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
setlocale(0, "rus");
int n, sum(0);
double i(0.0);
begin: cout << ("Введите натуральное число n: ") << endl;

cin >> n;
if (n < 0) goto begin;
int copy_n1 = n;
while (copy_n1 > 0)
{
    copy_n1 /= 10;
    ++i;
}
int copy_n2 = n;
const int copy_i = i;
for (int k = 0; k < copy_i; ++k)
    {
    i -= 1.0;
    double a = pow(10.0, i);
    int y = copy_n2 % int(a);
    /////// а дальше я не знаю, как делать
    }
cout << sum << endl;
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вы человеческими словами можете описать, как это определить?

Comment: Число `10` является палиндромом (`010`) или не является?

Comment: да читайте вы число как строку и всё. работы в разы меньше.

Comment: @pavel "работы в разы меньше" - уточните, пожалуйста, во сколько разов?

Comment: @Igor ну если читать как строку число - решение занимает 2 строки. тут написано 15

Comment: та-а-ак, значит, в семь с половиной разов

Comment: Палиндром - выражения которые одинаково читаются слева направо и справа налево. Например 101, 7, 55055 и т.д.

Comment: Игорь, я бы определил это так: Допустим, берем число 101; далее каким-то образом нужно разобрать его на цифры "1",  "0" и "1"; и, если из этих цифр составить число, читая цифры справа налево, и оно будет равно исходному, то это палиндром.

Comment: AnT, вот это "Число 10 является палиндромом (010) или не является?" я не знаю. Разве, если у этого числа тип int, оно не будет равно 10?

Comment: pavel, мне нужно как-то без строк)

Answer (score 2):

Желательно использовать рекурсивную функцию. Для упрощения решения проблемы можно использовать строковое представление данных. Предлагаю вариант использования нерекурсивной функции, данную вещь можно просто в main использовать.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int reverse_number(int number)
{
    int n = 0;
    while(number)
    {
        n = 10*n + number%10;
        number /= 10;
    }

 return n;
}


int main()
    cout << "input number: ";
    int number;
    cin >> number;
    if (number == reverse_number(number))
    cout << number << " This is palindrom" << endl;
    else
        cout << "NO " << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

не забудь прописать setlocate и так далее.

### Совет

---

> не используй go to - усложняет восприятие кода и качество кода, посторайся обходится без него

Comment: Очень благодарен!

Comment: И чем же рекурсия желательна?

Comment: С точки зрения удобства в таких задачах, можно и итеративно.

Answer (score 0):

Ну вот, например

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


using namespace std;


int main() {
  setlocale(0, "rus");
  cout << "Введите число: ";

  string num, rnum;
  getline(cin, num);

  rnum = num;
  _strrev(const_cast<char*>(rnum.c_str()));

  cout << ((num == rnum) ? "Это палиндром!" : "Это не палиндром...");

  return 0;
}
```

Вот вам вариант без строк. Могли бы и сами переделать, кстати - там легко разобраться, переделки чисто косметические.

```
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>


int main() {
  setlocale(0, "rus");
  printf("Введите число: ");

  char num[80], rnum[80];
  gets_s(num, sizeof(num));

  strcpy_s(rnum, sizeof(rnum), num);
  _strrev(rnum);

  printf(strcmp(num, rnum) == 0 ? "Это палиндром!" : "Это не палиндром...");

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: спасибо, но мне нужно без строк) @freim

Comment: @Тимофей Герасимчик, вот вам без строк, но все же и самому лениться не надо.

Comment: А разве вы сейчас не использовали строки? (Там же  strcpy_s..) И массивы? А задание вот:                                                                                                                                         
Как мне дописать этот код, не используя массивы, указатели, строки и тому подобное... Эта задача должна решаться как-то с помощью цикла.

Comment: @Тимофей Герасимчик, не понял сразу, думал вы под строками имеете в виду именно std::string.